# Why is referencing DbSet.Local slow in a loop?

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite

I'm using Entity-Framework 6.1.3 with a sqlite database.
During page load I'm initializing some properties in a loop (see below).

```
foreach (var trade in model.Trades)
{
    trade.ExchangeRates = Db.ExchangeRates.Local;
    trade.BaseCurrency = Prj_TradAc.Properties.Settings.Default.BaseCurrency;
}
```

Db.ExchangeRates.Local never hits the Database which is expected.
So I was expecting to only assign a reference to Db.ExchangeRates.Local which should be fast.
However with only ~500 Trades the loop takes almost 10s!

When I do the following

```
var ers = Db.ExchangeRates.Local;
foreach (var trade in model.Trades)
{
    trade.ExchangeRates = ers;
    trade.BaseCurrency = Prj_TradAc.Properties.Settings.Default.BaseCurrency;
}
```

the same loop with the same amount of data takes ~40ms

So why is accessing DBSet.Local so slow?

EDIT:

```
Db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnable = false
```

also makes the assignment fast. However I still do not understand why this is an issue here. My properties which I'm assigning to are just linked to fields - so no operation is going on here. There shouldn't be a change to the DBSet during assignment.

Comment: What happens if you set `Db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnable` to `false`?

Comment: @IvanStoev it's good -> 40ms

Comment: OK, if it's an already retrieved list then why you use like this inside the loop `Db.ExchangeRates.Local` ? In other words using `Db` again ?

Comment: @Sampath a Trade is a ViewModel which needs the ExchangeRates internally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime you **access** `Local` property (using the property getter), and [`DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.autodetectchangesenabled(v=vs.113).aspx) property is `true` (by default), EF calls `ObjectContext.DetectChanges` method which slows down the process.

Comment: Do you have any source of documentation for this behavior?

Comment: Negative. [Entity Framework Automatic Detect Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx) partially explains the concept, but this property is not included in the list. So when there is no documentation, fortunately there are tools to look at the source code :)

Comment: Thanks for the link - DbSet.Local is in the list

Comment: So is it safe to use OP's original workaround (that is, `var ers = Db.ExchangeRates.Local;`, and use that `ers` variable to acess `DbSet<>.Local` for following operations), especially if we are not just reading data but also possibly adding/modifying data?

Comment: @JyunhaoShih Yes, you can do that. But then you should keep in mind that the slow change detection is called by many other methods/properties of the context (listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/saving/change-tracking/auto-detect-changes?redirectedfrom=MSDN), while disabling AutoDetectChangesEnabled property eliminates all them, and the only thing you have to remember is to call DetectChanges before SaveChanges (or at points where you need to know the state of tracked entities).

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for answering. But can you explain more about what _points where you need to know the state of tracked entities_ means? The thing keeps bothering me is that Microsoft's docs never clearly stated the implications of setting `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` false, and how we should deal with them. I can't help thinking, if it's that safe to use the relevant methods/properties without detecting changes (except for those apparently need it such as `DbContext.SaveChanges` and `DbContext.GetValidationErrors`), then why did MS put it in so many methods at first?

Comment: @JyunhaoShih It's because you can modify the objects outside EF. Like changing object properties, or adding/removing objects from parent object collections instead of their db sets. EF needs to compare all objects and their collections with the "original" ones (maintained inside change tracker) to correctly identify added, modified and deleted entities.